# gnuradio-oot is not working when opencv library is used

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I'm trying to Port a C++ code as oot program of gnu radio, but errors occur when I  execute make after 'cmake' command,it looks like following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px06U.png)

It seems like the problem is the use of opencv in my C++ code of oot, related code is like this (in header file）:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include"cv.h"
using namespace cv;

Mat make_mat(Matrix<Type>Matrix_data);
Mat reshape_updown(Mat fftframel,Mat fftframeu,Mat B);
void bin2dec(Mat fftframeu, int result[]);
```

and in .cc file related code is like:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "cv.h"

using namespace cv;

Mat my_signal_detection_cb_impl::make_mat(Matrix<Type>Matrix_Data)
{
    ...
}
Mat my_signal_detection_cb_impl::reshape_updown(Mat fftframel, Mat fftframeu, Mat B)
{
    ...
}
void my_signal_detection_cb_impl::bin2dec(Mat fftframeu, int result[])
{
    ...
}
Mat fftframel = make_mat(fftframeL);
Mat fftframeu = make_mat(fftframeU);
```

This code uses some types in opencv like 'Mat' and functions, so I have no idea why make  reports this error and I can't find any other answers about this.

I have guessed if the cmakelist.txt have some error about address link so I tried to modify the cmakelist.txt and add the opencv address in it, but it didn't work, in fact I have add opencv and opencv2 folder in the place where the .cc and .h code are at first.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect the **error message** to be in the question post as **text**, not *linked* as *image*. Please, (re-)read [ask] and [edit] your question post accordingly.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)